# getJSON is not Working in IE for Youtube

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, youtube-api, getjson

In this function i am retriving data from Youtube using JSON. this function is working in Chrome and Mozilla . but it is not working in IE .

```
  function test(url){

      var youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
     $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+youtube_id+'?v=2&alt=json', function(data) {
      var title = data.entry.title.$t;
      var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
      var thumbnail = data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
       var imgdata = "<img src ='"+thumbnail+"' />";

    alert(title);
      });
      // alert(youtube_id);// Use these variables somewhere

  }
```

Can you help me ?

Thanx in Advance !!!

Comment: Have you tried to use the $.ajax() method and set JSON as data type?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting in ie? Are you trying to do this from an https domain?

Comment: @tkone not getting any error

Answer (score -1):

This is because IE (until IE 10) does not support [Cross-Domain Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

When you make the request with Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, etc, the browser first makes an `OPTIONS` request to the server and looks for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the headers, explaining, to the browser, which foreign sites are allowed to make a request against this domain.

The headers from the gdata API are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GData-User-Country: US
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Tue, 15 Jan 2013 15:02:28 GMT
Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2013 15:02:28 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=300, no-transform
Vary: *
GData-Version: 2.1
ETag: W/"C0EGQn47eCp7I2A9WhNbEks."
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Jan 2013 14:53:43 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
```

That `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header says that any foreign page (i.e. a page not served from the same protocol, host and port as the API being accessed) is allowed to call on this page.

IE, however, does not support the standard correctly.

You can, however, circumvent this using the JSONP standard, which the gdata API does support.

Change your `$.getJSON` call to include a `?` at the end of the URL.  This is how you explain to [jQuery that you'd like to use JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON) to make the call, which does allow for foreign sites.

e.g.:

```
var youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
     $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+youtube_id+'?v=2&alt=json?', function(data) {
        var title = data.entry.title.$t;
        var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
        var thumbnail = data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
        var imgdata = "<img src ='"+thumbnail+"' />";
        alert(title);
      });
```